# How to compute $\int_0^a \sin(\tan^{-1}(b\sin\theta))\ d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to compute

$$\int_0^a \sin(\tan^{-1}(b\sin\theta))\ d\theta$$

I've tried to rewrite it as

$$\int_0^a\frac{b\sin\theta}{\sqrt{b^2\sin^2\theta+1}}d\theta$$

But I'm still stuck here.

Comment: A "little"... ?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sin%28arctan%28b+sin+x%29%29+dx) gives:$$\left[-\dfrac{b\ln(\sqrt{-2b^2}\cos x+\sqrt{b^2(-\cos(2x))+b^2+2})}{\sqrt{-b^2}}\right]^a_0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here one way to go about just using the regular techniques one may learn in a calc class.

The way you have it written: $$b\int_{0}^{a}\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{b^{2}\sin^{2}\theta +1}}d\theta$$ is a good start.

Now, use the identity $\sin\theta = 1-\cos^{2}\theta$

$$b\int_{0}^{a}\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{b^{2}(1-\cos^{2}\theta)+1}}d\theta$$

Let $u=\cos\theta, \;\ du=-\sin\theta d\theta$

$$-b\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^{2}(1-u^{2})}}du$$

Let $u=\sin(y)\frac{\sqrt{b^{2}+1}}{b}, \;\ du=\frac{\sqrt{b^{2}+1}}{b}\cos(y), \;\ y=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{ub}{\sqrt{b^{2}+1}}\right)$

Making these subs now results in everything cancelling down to:

$$-b\int \frac{\sqrt{b^{2}+1}}{b}\cos(y)\cdot \frac{1}{\cos(y)\sqrt{b^{2}+1}}dy$$

$$=-\int dy$$

$$y=-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{ub}{\sqrt{b^{2}+1}}\right)$$

Revert $u=\cos(\theta)$

$$-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{b\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{b^{2}+1}}\right)$$

Now, use the limits of integration to get:

$$\tan^{-1}(b)-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{b\cos(a)}{\sqrt{b^{2}+1}}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks! This helps, but I believe you missed a $+1$ in the second step, as well as a negative in the third.

Comment: Yes, you are certainly correct. I fixed them Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: How did you get from the $\sqrt{b^{2}(1-u^{2})}$ to $\cos(y)\sqrt{b^{2}+1}$?

Comment: nevermind, I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The change of variables
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{b+1}{b}x
$$
gives
$$
\int\frac{b\sin\theta}{\sqrt{b^2\sin^2\theta+1}}d\theta=-\sqrt{b^2+1}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.
$$
Let's check it:
$$
\sin\theta\,d\theta=-\frac{b+1}{b}dx,
$$
$$
b^2\sin^2\theta+1=b^2(1-\cos^2\theta)+1=b^2(1-\frac{(b+1)^2}{b^2}x^2)+1=(b^2+1)(1-x^2).
$$

Comment: May you share how you achieved that?